# mime-formatted file is losing dots when they appear on line-breaks

Tags: c#, file, encoding, mime

I am writing a mime-formatted email message file containing html.  I am writing the html portion of the mime file as follows:

```
writer.WriteLine("--" + altBoundary);
writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
writer.WriteLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable");
writer.WriteLine();
QuotedPrintableEncoder qpEncoder=new QuotedPrintableEncoder();
writer.WriteLine(qpEncoder.Encode(HTMLBody));
```

In the HTMLBody I have a large chunk of html.  One fragment of this looks as follows:

```
<p><br />Dear Ben,<br /><br />

              Thank you for your interest in our products and services.
   =
          =20
              </p>

              <p>Here are some literature links you may find interesting:<=
/p>

              <ul><li><a  title=3D"Brochure One"  href=3D"http://xxxxxshow=
.xxxpoint.com/Document?client=3DXxxxxxpoint&document=3DBrochure One">Broch=
ure One</a></li></ul>

              Regards,<br />
```

Note the //xxxxxshow.xxxpoint.com domain, which spans a line break in the mime file.  When this domain arrives in Outlook it has 'lost the first dot, so it reads xxxxshowxxxpoint.com, whereas it should read xxxxxshow.xxxpoint.com. If a line break occurs so that the dot is the very first character on the next line, the dot gets 'lost', and is missing from the source of the email when it arrives in Outlook.  If the line break occurs half-way through the word 'xxxxxshow' then the dot does not get lost, and it does appear in email within outlook.

What is going on, and how do I fix this?

Comment: How are you sending file? Are you directly communicating with SMTP server?

Comment: No, I'm just writing the file directly into the SMTP pickup dir

Comment: Then I guess the server doesn't encode the files correctly. You should probably report that as a bug to the manufacturer/maintainer of the server you're using.

Comment: Sure.  Might a different encoding circumvent the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like you're not encoding the text of the e-mail for SMTP correctly. [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP#SMTP_transport_example):

> Since a message body can contain a line with just a period as part of the text, the client sends two periods every time a line starts with a period; correspondingly, the server replaces every sequence of two periods at the beginning of a line with a single one. Such escaping method is called *dot-stuffing*.

Basically, whenever you want to write a period at the start of a line, you have to write two periods instead.

Comment: So the .NET QuotedPrintableEncoder class is not writing the info correctly?

Comment: Should I be using a different encoding to write this part of the file?

Comment: No, `QuotedPrintableEncoder` correctly encodes the text using the quoted-printable encoding. But it doesn't know you're going to use that text for SMTP, which adds its own dot-stuffing. Dot-stuffing is specific to SMTP, it has nothing to do with MIME or quoted-printable.

Comment: If you used base64, that would work around the issue, because it never contains a period in the encoded form. But it also bloats the size by about one third, which may or may not matter to you.

Comment: I'd rather say that **SMTP client (or server that picks it up) is broken**. It's its responsibility to do the dot-stuffing. Certainly not the user nor QuotedPrintableEncoder nor MIME parser.

Comment: In the end I encoded using base64, which circumvents the problem with the Microsoft SMTP server.  Thanks svick.